# window.location.href not working in my code but window.location.replace is working

Tags: jquery, window.location

in my code i cant redirect to new page when login is correct, instead of "window.location.href" ,window.location.replace is working.how to make this code working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(){

        $('.errordisp').empty();

        var spgremail=$('#mailid').val();
        var spgrpwd=$('#pwd').val();
        if(spgremail=='' || spgrpwd==''){

            var txt=$('#errormsg8').text();
            $('.errordisp').append(txt);//removeClass('hidden').addClass('errordisp');

        }
        else
        {
            $.post("in.php",{email: spgremail,pass: spgrpwd},function(data) {

                if(data)
                {

                    window.location.href("http://abcd.com/discover.php");

                }
                else
                {
                     txt=$('#errormsg3').text();
                    $('.errordisp').append(txt);
                }

            });

        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window.location.href` property is not a function, you have to assign the url to it like

```
window.location.href = "http://abcd.com/discover.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code

this

```
window.location.href("http://abcd.com/discover.php");
```

to

```
window.location.href="http://abcd.com/discover.php";
```

window.location.href is not a method, it's a property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser